# Missing "dev" script in package.json when trying to run "npm run dev."

Tags: npm, three.js, web-development-server, npm-run

I am facing some terrible problem as I installed npm using my vs code terminal... but when I try to run

```
npm run dev 
its throws some error..
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\dasha\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-09-18T14_22_40_412Z-debug-0.log
```

and my package.json file looks somthing like..

```
{

  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.156.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vite": "^4.4.9"
  }
}
```

can anyone help..?

I tried manually fixing the package.json file by adding

```
  "name": "threejs_tut",
  "private": true,
  "version": "4.4.9",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
```

then it shows

```
> threejs_tut@0.0.0 dev
> vite


  VITE v4.4.9  ready in 188 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose
  ➜  press h to show help
```

and link doesn't work

Comment: You fixed the error you're actually asking about by... providing a `dev` script. So what's the problem with the link?